# How to overwrite orderby with add_query_var

Tags: php, wp-query, loop, query

So I would like to have an archive that displays its posts in a random order.

```
<?php    
    $query = new WP_Query($query_string."&orderby=rand");
?>
```

But also then if the user chooses they can order the posts differently by clicking a button.

```
<?php
    $sort_date = add_query_arg(array('orderby'=>'date','order'=>'asc'));
    $sort_name = add_query_arg(array('orderby'=>'title','order'=>'asc'));
?>

<div class="sort">
    Sort by: <a href="<?php echo $sort_date; ?>">Date Listed</a> | <a href="<?php echo  $sort_name; ?>">Name</a>
</div>
```

These 2 things work separately but when I try and use them together the archive just keeps display the posts randomly.

How can I get these 2 to work together?

Comment: Order parameter in your `WP_Query` statement is missing.

Comment: Thats because its not needed, WP_Query Order parameter defaults to desc.

Comment: Sorry, I meant `orderby`. Anyway, you are always querying with `orderby=rand`. So, obviously it will always show random post. You should have some condition check to have value of `orderby` to `rand` or `date` or `title`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I finally figured it out.

Using `pre_get_posts` and the `$_GET` global var to check if any query args have been added works a treat.

I used the follow code to get the desired results.

```
function my_pre_get_posts($query) {
    if(
        $query->is_main_query() && 
        is_archive() && 
        !isset($_GET['orderby']) && // checks for query args
        !is_admin()
    ) {
        $query->set('orderby','rand');
    }
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'my_pre_get_posts');
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `pre_get_posts` instead..

```
function my_archive_query_override( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_archive() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'orderby', 'rand' );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_archive_query_override' );
```

For that user selectable part, you can use AJAX to accomplish that.